# Oracle PL/SQL's dbms_output.put_line() vs dbms_output.put()

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have a trivial question, I yet to understand the difference between dbms_output.put_line()  and  dbms_output.put()

```
set serveroutput on size 200000
Begin
dbms_output.put_line('A' || CHR(10) || 'B');
End;
/

exec dbms_output.put_line('A' || CHR(10) || 'B');
```

The above gives output **A** and **B** in two different lines. But

```
exec dbms_output.put('A')
exec dbms_output.put('B')
exec dbms_output.new_line
```

prints nothing. I am using **SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production**

Answer (score 5):

You always have to write full lines in each PL/SQL block. Wehn you write

```
Begin
  dbms_output.put_line('A' || CHR(10) || 'B');
End;
/
```

You write the two full lines "A" and "B" in one PL/SQL block. When you write

```
exec dbms_output.put_line('A' || CHR(10) || 'B');
```

the same holds true.

But when you write

```
exec dbms_output.put('A')
exec dbms_output.put('B')
exec dbms_output.new_line
```

you have three separate PL/SQL blocks. The first two write partial lines, which will be skipped by SqlPlus. The third block writes a full, but empty line.

If you write

```
begin
  dbms_output.put('A');
 dbms_output.put('B');
 dbms_output.new_line;
end;
/
```

everything works as expected.

The reason for this is how console output in SqlPlus works: PL/SQL writes the output in an intermediate buffer. SqlPlus fetches the content of this buffer at the end of each executed PL/SQL block. It then prints that content to the console, while only printing full lines. Hence it skips the last line in the buffer, when it is not terminated by a new line character.

<del>Technically I suspect SqlPlus to also print lines without a new line character, but starightaway overwrite them in the next step.</del> Technically SqlPlus indeed fetches only full lines from the internal buffer, using the [`DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_output.htm#BABJCAJA) PL/SQL function.

Comment: In fact, all the tools having the ability to display the dbms_output uses DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on 11g, you should be considering PUT procedure since it is **Obsolete and no longer supported by Oracle**. In previous versions, with PUT, the line is not yet completed. Since it doesn't have end of line marker unlike PUT_LINE which automatically is followed by an end-of-line marker.

So, **if you add an end-of-line marker, you will get the output.**

You can have a look at this old question [Is dbms_output.put() being buffered differently from dbms_output.put_line()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532211/is-dbms-output-put-being-buffered-differently-from-dbms-output-put-line)

Comment: Yes, of course it works. That's what I meant, PUT needs a end-of-line marker. and then NEW_LINE to let the buffered output printed.

Comment: From the docs: "The `PUT` procedure that takes a `NUMBER` is obsolete", not the version the OP is using. The same is true for `PUT_LINE`.

Comment: Ok, I saw that in docs. Dan Morgan made a statement in his site http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_output.html